# Is there support for appium on mac m2 machine

Tags: appium-ios

I am facing several issues while trying to launch my application from appium inspector on apple mac m2 machine . I tried for both simulator(using .app) and real device(using .ipa) . Hence wanted to check if there is any support for appium on mac m2 machine as the last release appears to be around the same time MacBook Air with M2 chip was launched.

I have installed all the pre-requisites. I have also checked the installations through appium doctor and there are no issues. Created a build. Started the appium server and entered the Desired capabilities through appium inspector and try to give Start session . But facing the below error :

Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Simulator architecture is unsupported by the '/Users/e5662282/fcb_mb.app' application. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Appium should support Mac M2.

The error that you see is because the app is not built for the simulator.

You will need to build the .app file from Xcode or from the command line and select the target as simulator. You can follow the steps from here:

https://help.perfecto.io/perfecto-help/content/perfecto/automation-testing/create_an_ios_simulator_build.htm

You can also refer this defect on Appium GitHub that has similar issue: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/17649